# Magento 2 Block Template Path

Tags: magento2

I'm getting this error trying to create a .phtml template.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'CleverSoft_Base::images_dimensions_chart.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

I don't understand the two :: after CleverSoft_Base what does those two dots stand for and what should be the path in my child theme for the overwrite?

Answer (score 1):

If you're overwriting a template your have to set your own module

```
Vendor_Module::images_dimensions_chart.phtml
```

the base-path for frontend templates in your module is always `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates`